Getting CKEDITOR issue
Hi I am getting below error while using CKEDITOR, in jQuery. Withour any data it is working fine, but if we have any data in CKEDITOR it's giving below error
ckeditor.js:203 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'strong')
at h (ckeditor.js:203:458)
at CKEDITOR.filter.applyTo (ckeditor.js:211:308)
at a.<anonymous> (ckeditor.js:299:264)
at a.n (ckeditor.js:10:224)
at a.<anonymous> (ckeditor.js:12:47)
at CKEDITOR.editor.CKEDITOR.editor.fire (ckeditor.js:13:242)
at CKEDITOR.htmlDataProcessor.toHtml (ckeditor.js:301:447)
at $.setData (ckeditor.js:788:106)
at $.<anonymous> (ckeditor.js:352:32)
at a.n (ckeditor.js:10:224)


a lot missing here ... which ckeditor version, how did you include that, can you show code and show what you tried and where you failed?
